How can I install mytop on newer versions of Ubuntu?
I would like to install the tool mytop in order to monitor SQL queries in my MySQL database. I have seen information out there instructing users to install mytop using apt, but I get this error:
$ sudo apt install mytop
Package mytop is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
   mariadb-client

E: Package 'mytop' has no installation candidate

It looks like the latest version of Ubuntu to include mytop in its repositories is Ubuntu Ubuntu 22.04 LTS (jammy). The next version of Ubuntu, which is Ubuntu 22.10 (kinetic), does not include this package in its repositories.
How can I install mytop?

Debian decided to remove the mytop package from its repositories (see bug #1026428), because the upstream source for mytop is not maintained, and has not seen a release since 2010. This change propagated to Ubuntu's repositories.
MariaDB does ship a mytop executable, which serves the same function. MySQL and MariaDB are alternatives to each other, and Debian/Ubuntu only allow you to have one installed at a time. So you can't use this version of mytop with MySQL.
You can run this command to get a result similar to what you would get with mytop (replacing databesname with the name of your database):
watch -n 0.1 -x mysql databasename -e 'show full processlist'

